# Can I import a blank table into other pages

Tags: css

I am researching a second world war convoy and intend to put the result up on the web. I have to record dozens of signals and have designed a table which will suit my purpose however I do not want to copy and paste each one – is it possible to insert using some form of script and place the import where I want it on the webpage? I should add that each webpage could have 10 or more signals on it.

I am thinking along the lines having something in the head called “signalstable” and then when I want to insert the said table just put  at the appropriate place

If you are kind enough to reply please bear in mind that whilst I understand the basics of html and css I am in my mi 70’s and not as quick as you youngsters

Thanks for any help/suggestion you can provide

David

Comment: you could include your table to all pages and hide it via CSS: `display: none` and then when needed change CSS to `display: block` on the table via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please do NOT consider this an answer. I'm just providing a little more information based on Rumplin's excellent comment. I've done this a couple of times on some of my pages.

1. The files that "grab" the table from the server must have shtml or php extensions.
2. The "include" lines look like this in general:

> ```
> <!--#include file="../subdirectory/myspecialtable.html"-->
> <?php include '../subdirectory/myspecialtable.php'  ?>
> ```

HTML/PHP file

```
<table class='myspecialtabale'>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.myspecialtable {
  display: none;
}
```